# How to upload a document to SharePoint using WebServices

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have looked through multiple tutorials and asked many questions with NO result . Here it is step by step :

1) I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 . I do NOT have SP server installed and cannot use Microsoft.SharePoint.dll . However , I can use Web Service

2) I create a console project and add a WebReference like this

[image]

3) Here is my FULL code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ConsoleApplication6;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {

            string srcUrl = @"C:\\xxx\\test.txt";
            System.IO.FileStream fStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(srcUrl);
            string fileName = fStream.Name.Substring(3);
            byte[] contents = new byte[fStream.Length];
            fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
            fStream.Close();

            ServiceWebReference.Lists listService = new ServiceWebReference.Lists(); // "Lists" get underlined with a red line ?
            listService.ClientCredentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            try
            {
                // adding attachment
                string result = listService.AddAttachment("testList", "1", fileName, contents);
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }

            catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.GetBaseException());
                Console.WriteLine(e);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I adding the reference in a right way ? If yes , then why does the `ServiceWebReference.Lists listService ... ... ...` get underlined in red (does not recognize namespace ) ?

How to make the code work ?

Comment: Are you wanting to add the document as an attachment to a new list item, an existing list item, or as a new document in a document library? My recommendation will differ based on this.

Comment: Ideally, I wanted to upload a new document to a document library . However, after multiple attempts I will be happy to be able to do ANY of the above :)

Comment: Can anybody provide a DETAILED code with all references and all `usings` I found multiple examples online but could not get them to work . Maybe it is because I am adding the Web Service in a wrong way

Comment: Your client is named `ServiceWebReference.ListsSoapClient`. Use  `ServiceWebReference.ListsSoapClientclient = new ServiceWebReference.ListsSoapClient();`

Answer (score 0):

Since `Lists.asmx` is a SOAP Web service, it could be referenced as described in article: [How to: Add a Reference to a Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx)

How to add `Lists.asmx` SOAP Web service in Visual Studio:

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the name of the project that you want to add the service to, and then click `Add Service Reference`
2. The `Add Service Reference` dialog box appears, in the `Service Reference Settings` dialog box, click `Add Web Reference` as demonstrated below
3. Specify service endpoint Url
        [image]

Visual Studio

[image]

Sample code

```
namespace SPUpload
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var attachmentUrl = UploadAttachment(@"c:\temp\usermanual.rtf","Phones","1");
        }


        private static string UploadAttachment(string filePath, string listName, string listItemId)
        {
            var listsSvc = new ListsService.Lists();
            listsSvc.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            var fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            return listsSvc.AddAttachment(listName, listItemId, fileName, fileContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1: there is no reason to resort to the legacy "Add Web Reference".

Comment: Thank you Vadim . Could you provide a full example . I tried  `listService.ClientCredentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;` and it was underlined in red .